# Create 2 level pivot table in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with different values, and I want to build a "pivot table" using R, but with 2 levels, and I know how to group it by 1 level, but not 2.

This is the result I'm expecting:
[2 level pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnY8.png)

`Region/Country   Sales 
Asia            3,452,710
  China         3,452,710
Europe          2,881,793
  Germany       1,846,392
  Spain         1,035,401
South America   3,111,193
  Argentina     1,059,341
  Brazil        2,051,852`

This is an example of the data, and I want to group it bye Region and Country.

Country Region  Sales

`China   Asia    $109,680
China   Asia    $141,165
China   Asia    $77,516
China   Asia    $154,060
China   Asia    $38,597
China   Asia    $125,985
China   Asia    $91,850
China   Asia    $90,513
China   Asia    $51,710
China   Asia    $53,283
China   Asia    $77,352
China   Asia    $5,534
China   Asia    $6,645
China   Asia    $135,301
China   Asia    $176,095
China   Asia    $146,270
China   Asia    $54,665
China   Asia    $62,111
China   Asia    $64,390
China   Asia    $30,197
China   Asia    $132,397
China   Asia    $165,454
China   Asia    $113,084
China   Asia    $40,922
China   Asia    $161,574
China   Asia    $16,753
China   Asia    $54,616
China   Asia    $117,857
China   Asia    $193,862
China   Asia    $23,478
China   Asia    $16,135
China   Asia    $103,860
China   Asia    $72,478
China   Asia    $45,570
China   Asia    $81,337
China   Asia    $174,224`

Comment: What do you mean by your expected output? Do you want a data frame? Or are you putting this in a report - do you want an HTML or LaTeX formatted table? Something else? Can you share your code for grouping by 1 level and show what you've tried for grouping by two levels? How is your raw data structured? By two levels, do you mean Region and Country or Region and Overall? Can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks Gregor.
The expected output is a table, that I can print into a CSV file, but grouped in two levels, in this example, total sales, by region and by country.

Raw data is structured in columns in a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to answer this without reproducible datasets, but here is goes. Try to install dplyr and the hflights library to work with the code sample.

```
#install.packages("hflights")
#install.packages("dplyr")

library(dplyr)
library(hflights)

head(hflights)

# filter data for 2011 inbound flights to DFW
data_2011_DFW <- filter(hflights, Dest == "DFW", Year == 2011, Month == 1)

# group by Destination Airport and Month
data_2011_DFW_Carrier <- group_by(data_2011_DFW, UniqueCarrier)

# create a custom summary of observations
summarize(data_2011_DFW_Carrier, count = n(), delay = mean(ArrDelay, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of the data, and I want to group it bye Region and Country.

```
Country Region  Sales
China   Asia    $109,680
China   Asia    $141,165
China   Asia    $77,516
China   Asia    $154,060
China   Asia    $38,597
China   Asia    $125,985
China   Asia    $91,850
China   Asia    $90,513
China   Asia    $51,710
China   Asia    $53,283
China   Asia    $77,352
China   Asia    $5,534
China   Asia    $6,645
China   Asia    $135,301
China   Asia    $176,095
China   Asia    $146,270
China   Asia    $54,665
China   Asia    $62,111
China   Asia    $64,390
China   Asia    $30,197
China   Asia    $132,397
China   Asia    $165,454
China   Asia    $113,084
China   Asia    $40,922
China   Asia    $161,574
China   Asia    $16,753
China   Asia    $54,616
China   Asia    $117,857
China   Asia    $193,862
China   Asia    $23,478
China   Asia    $16,135
China   Asia    $103,860
China   Asia    $72,478
China   Asia    $45,570
China   Asia    $81,337
China   Asia    $174,224
China   Asia    $58,030
China   Asia    $188,160
Spain   Europe  $118,446
Spain   Europe  $43,783
Spain   Europe  $52,586
Spain   Europe  $42,995
Spain   Europe  $183,739
Spain   Europe  $108,905
Spain   Europe  $100,986
Spain   Europe  $155,873
Spain   Europe  $117,634
Spain   Europe  $110,454
Germany Europe  $118,446
Germany Europe  $43,783
Germany Europe  $52,586
Germany Europe  $42,995
Germany Europe  $183,739
Germany Europe  $108,905
Germany Europe  $100,986
Germany Europe  $155,873
Germany Europe  $117,634
Germany Europe  $110,454
Germany Europe  $61,951
Germany Europe  $139,379
Germany Europe  $97,083
Germany Europe  $41,821
Germany Europe  $26,241
Germany Europe  $39,150
Germany Europe  $26,485
Germany Europe  $104,995
Germany Europe  $75,915
Germany Europe  $197,971
Brazil  South America   $20,063
Brazil  South America   $96,114
Brazil  South America   $78,454
Brazil  South America   $181,765
Brazil  South America   $145,676
Brazil  South America   $133,124
Brazil  South America   $142,922
Brazil  South America   $190,313
Brazil  South America   $5,764
Brazil  South America   $77,970
Brazil  South America   $196,077
Argentina   South America   $64,547
Argentina   South America   $157,579
Argentina   South America   $87,654
Argentina   South America   $184,358
Argentina   South America   $25,555
Argentina   South America   $38,456
Argentina   South America   $6,762
Argentina   South America   $49,041
Argentina   South America   $178,130
Argentina   South America   $180,618
Argentina   South America   $86,641
Brazil  South America   $18,330
Brazil  South America   $28,143
Brazil  South America   $130,999
Brazil  South America   $100,090
Brazil  South America   $59,515
Brazil  South America   $157,308
Brazil  South America   $170,736
Brazil  South America   $106,259
Brazil  South America   $12,230
```

Comment: Daniel, is not an answer to the question. Please modify your original question and add this as additional information.

Comment: Hi, I've modified the question.